# IntelliJ can't use more than 1950MB of RAM after upgrade to Snow Leopard

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently upgraded to Snow Leopard and it seems IntelliJ can't start with memory greater than 
-Xmx1950m. The icon bounces in the dock, but nothing comes up.

My guess would be that it's trying to use a 32-bit version of Java, but everything seems correct. Did anybody run into this when upgrading?

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling IntelliJ fixed the problem. My guess is that something was wrong in the IntelliJ's info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it's [not set to run in 32-bit mode](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1232)?

Another possible case if you had modified Info.plist manually and updated to 10.0.2 via patch, the file was not updated to the new version which can run in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it.